# Picky: Wording on privileges explanation site slightly inconsistent

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, wording

I noticed that there is a small inconsistency in the wording on https://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges (see annotated screenshot below). It appears also on all other StackExchange sites.

In the right bar listing all privileges it says 'edit questions and answers'. When clicking the link the corresponding article also has this headline but the first paragraph starts with 'What is edit everything'. I assume the name of this used to be 'edit everything' and changed later. I found it confusing for a second but recovered quickly :-)

I don't know what effort it takes to change this and if it's worthwhile at all.

---

[image]

Comment: I don't find "edit everything" a helpful description either; you *can't* edit tag wikis (without moderation) yet, so it's obviously not *everything* is it?

Comment: Clearly, the correct wording should be "EDIT ALL THE THINGS!!"

Comment: You *can* [suggest edits to the privilege wikis](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-wiki/15).  I imagine this request would be probably get approved =) (note: you can only do this through the Meta Stack Overflow privileges page, because it's the template for the other sites)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Thanks for the explanation. Btw, the link you posted give me a 'Page not found'.

Comment: It looks like @Kiamlaluno has already [fixed it now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66737/10).  Not sure why he hasn't posted an answer to indicate that though.

Comment: @jadarnel27 oh, wow, I didn't know that even existed.

Comment: @BenBrocka The knowledge is fairly new to me as well.  Oh, and sorry user12999, I didn't realize that suggested privilege wiki edits must have a minimum rep requirement.

Comment: We'll get these meta changes pushed out to all sites tomorrow.  Thanks for updating the wiki, kiamlaluno.

Comment: @JarrodDixon while it seems to be updated on stacksverflow it's not yet on http://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit
(as far as I can see it's not a cache issue). Can you check?